# using multiple databases in multiple environments with laravel

Tags: database-design, laravel-5, architecture

I've got an architectural conundrum with a Laravel 5.2 application I'm writing. The app connects to multiple database servers in production; I've set up Vagrant environments for all of the devs and we all pull the data we need from production into our virtual environments to ensure that the databases are a mirror of production. The problem comes in when we want to do our testing; I can't seem to set the application up in such a way that Model A (which connects to DB1) and Model B (which connects to DB2) can both be tested in the same SQLite file (which is in the repo pre-configured). Might make more sense looking at sample config files:

My database config file:

```
<?php

return [
    'default' => 'platform',
    'connections' => [
        'platform' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('PLATFORM_HOST'),
            // ...
        ],
        'product' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('PRODUCT_HOST'),
            // ...
        ],
        'testing' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path().'/testing.db'
        ]
    ]
];
```

A typical platform model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Platform;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ModelA extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'platform';
    protected $table = 'table_a';
}
```

And a typical product model, very nearly identical:

```
<?php

namespace App\Product;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ModelB extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'product';
    protected $table = 'table_b';
}
```

The root cause of my problem is that the model's `$connection` value overrides the value set in the environment config file, as well as the environment value set in `phpunit.xml`. If I don't set the `$connection` value on the model, it uses whatever is set for the environment default...which is fine if I'm testing a platform model, because that's the default connection. But when I'm testing a product model, I have to do one of two things, neither of which I care for: in the model constructor, detect the `testing` environment and do something like `$this->connection() = 'testing';`; or in my `setUp()` method on the test, do something like `Config::set('database.connections.platform', Config::get('database.connections.testing'));`.

I feel like there are half a dozen ways to do this, none of which are very clean. Right now I'm taking the second approach - overriding the `Config` values for the non-default connection with the `Config` values for the `testing` connection - but I kinda don't like myself for doing that. I thought about switching to a repository pattern but the implementation of my model's methods don't change, just the type of database they're using in the underlying connection. I'm at a loss for what else to try. Any suggestions?